# Package a python application with html/css/js frontend as a single executable

Tags: python, webkit

I have a small application that has a html/css/js frontend (written by someone else) and a python backend that runs a small WSGI server via flask. Currently the python side is bundled up with py2exe and the frontend is distributed alongside.

However, it would be preferable if it would be possible to somehow call WebKit (or some other canvas/css3 supporting browser renderer) from python to start the html frontend without the usual browser chrome to give the impression that it is not a web app but a "real, native application"?

Comment: What about `PyQt4.QtWebKit`?  You'd have to wrap the view in a basic Qt UI, but it seems like you should be able to drive everything via the existing front end you have.

Comment: Can't use PyQt4 because of the GPL. I'm trying to see if pywebkitgtk has a recent windows port.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, QT has a `qtwebkit` module and there are several bindings for QT in python, the chief amongst them being PyQt4. However, PyQt4 is licensed either under the GPL or a paid-for propriatary license. All is not lost as Nokia have developed their own python bindings called [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aLanguageBindings%3a%3aPySide) which can be used to embed webkit in a python application through the `qtwebkit` module.